# Cannot implicitly convert type `string' to `System.Collections.Generic.List<int>'

Tags: c#

This should compare three numbers that are on each list and give a point to C if the number in A is greater than the number in B or a point to D if the number in B is greater than the number in A and will do nothing if They are equal. Here is an example:

```
Input     | output
A= 1 3 2  |  C D
B= 3 2 2  |  1 1
```

Here's the code:

```cs
static List<int> compareTriplets(List<int> a, List<int> b)
{
    int c = 0;
    int d = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] > b[i])
        {
            c++;
        }
        else if (b[i] > a[i])
        {
            d++;
        }
    }
    return c + " " + d;
}
```

This code returns me this:

> error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>'

Comment: You should return `List<int>` but you are returning `c +" "+ d`. I don't understand the rest of the question.

Comment: try  return c[i].ToString() +" "+ d[i].ToString;

Comment: @JuniorCortenbach: that won't work. It's still a string

Comment: Maybe return signature should be `string`?

Comment: Yes you are right  Thomas but I am think like  Apce that the return signature should be a string.

Comment: Take some time to think about what you're doing. What is the function supposed to return? Should it return a string? Or should it return a list with two values in it?

Comment: @SpiritBob: agree. For a beginner, he at least provided a minimal code example. Not that bad.

Comment: Thank you very much to all who answered my question and as you already said I am a complete beginner it did not take more than 2 or 3 months to start learning c #

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me, this piece of code looks like you want to return 2 numbers:

> ```
> return c + " " + d;
> ```

However, this way it will become a string, which dies not match the method signature.

To return a list of numbers (e.g. 2 numbers), you can use

```
return new List<int>{c, d};
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to convert a string to List. The function `compareTriplets` must return a string.

An advice: you need to check bounds of list when iterate using index.

```
static string compareTriplets(List<int> a, List<int> b)
{
    int c = 0;
    int d = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] > b[i])
            c++;
        else if (b[i] > a[i])
            d++;
    }
    return c + " " + d;
}
```

Using C# 6.0+, you can return like this:

```
return $"{c} {d}";
```

Comment: You're concatenating integer types to string types in your `return`.

Comment: The string is converted implicitly @JoshuaSchlichting

Comment: @JoshuaSchlichting: it will compile and run. [Try it yourself.](https://ideone.com/x9f1pY)

Comment: Interesting. I thought a cast would be appropriate there.

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying that your function will return a list of integers: `static List<int>`. You need to change this to string.

```
static String compareTriplets(List<int> a, List<int> b) {
    int c = 0;
    int d = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
        if (a[i]>b[i]){
           c++;
        }
        else if (b[i]>a[i])
        {
            d++;
        }
    }
    return c.ToString() + " " + d.ToString();
 }
```

EDIT: Explicit `ToString()` cast isn't required.

If you truly want to return a `List<int>`, do the following:

```
static List<int> compareTriplets(List<int> a, List<int> b) {
    int c = 0;
    int d = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
        if (a[i]>b[i]){
           c++;
        }
        else if (b[i]>a[i])
        {
            d++;
        }
    }
    return new List<int>(){ c, d };
 }
```

Comment: You don't need to call `ToString`, it will do that automatically for you. This is true for every `object`, not only `int`.

Comment: My mistake! I prefer to by explicit, but I didn't realize int didn't have a .toString()!

Comment: It has a `ToString()` with an upper T.

Answer (score 0):

Your return type is `string`: `a + " " + b`, so you need to change method signature:

```cs
static string compareTriplets(List<int> a, List<int> b) {
    // etc....
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return type `List<int>` but you are returning `c +" "+ d`. I don't understand the rest of the question.

You should return a list. Here's an example:

```
static List<int> compareTriplets(List<int> a, List<int> b) 
{
    int c = 0;
    int d = 0;

    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
        if (a[i]>b[i])
            c++;
        else if (b[i]>a[i])
            d++;

    return new List<int>{ c, d };
 }
```